# how I remove default value from dateedit

Tags: c#, datetime, devexpress

When I try to add a new user on my form on the datetimes add *01.01.0001* value automatically on datimedits.

I declared datetimes in a class , and in the `SQL` table the datetimes field is `nullable` but I couldn't remove this date from the startup.

```
private DateTime _JobStartDate = DateTime.MinValue;
private DateTime _JobEndDate = DateTime.MinValue;
```

thanks.

Comment: maybe you have to check the value and if its null, then set current date to example?

Comment: Elif welcome to SO. I tried to edit and correct spelling, typos of you question but it still doesn't seem to be so understandable. What is your *form*? is it a windows form or asp.net form or something else? What are controls in it? where is 01.01.0001 added automatically? in database or in your form? Can you please expand your description and add source code

Comment: As @Compulim descriped you have to make it Nullable. If you got the problem inside of DateEdit you should use the EditValue instead of the DateTime Property.

Answer (score 2):

You should declare your `DateTime` as `Nullable<T>`. `DateTime?` is a shorthand for `Nullable<DateTime>`.

```
private DateTime? _JobStartDate = null;
private DateTime? _JobEndDate = null;
```

More details at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullable(v=vs.110).aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Well. You are setting the datetimes to DateTime.MinValue (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minvalue(v=vs.110).aspx). So it works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

when I use this

private DateTime? _JobStartDate = null;
private DateTime? _JobEndDate = null;

It was solved. I know "now" parameter but I dont wanna use any time in my dateedit I want it empty, thanks for all answers.